# Can't access Outlook and can't upload to Upwork - connected?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, upload, outlook-web-access

For two days now I have been having two issues: first, I can't access my Outlook account (web app), all I get is the "something went wrong" message.

The other problem is that I can't upload files to Upwork (as message attachments), and while this might just be a coincidence, I am wondering if these two things could be connected and caused by something on my end.

**Notes:**

- I can't access Outlook from different computers in my house, but I can access it from my phone via the Outlook app
- The Upwork problem isn't browser-related, it doesn't work on different browsers and doesn't work in the desktop app either
- I am using Google's DNS servers
- Yes, I have tried restarting my computer.

I am already starting to feel as if this isn't just a coincidence, since it has already been going on for two days. At least, I'd like to know if perhaps someone else is experiencing similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well first it depends on which domain your are using using Outlook, it is  @outlook.com, @hotmail.com, @live.com, or @msn.com. Next thing is you should go for microsoft KB aricle discussing this same issue. here is the link [**https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2620052**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2620052)

Thanks & Regards
Sandra Diaz